# my question is about gibbs energy, entropy and all that

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

1. I learnt that Gibbs energy is a free energy to do work! Tell me, what is this free energy and what is the work done (I mean what kind of work). Please also provide me an example of Gibbs free energy, like which energy and what work it is doing.
2. Entropy is said to be a measure of randomness in a gas...is there any device which measures randomness in a body? Based on this, the second law of thermodynamics states that it is not possible to have a process in which the entropy of isolated system is decreased - what does this mean?
3. Suppose we take a Carnot engine diagram: We will see it is a cyclic process so change in internal energy is zero therefore work done = heat change, so if we take the formula for efficiency as the ratio of work done to the change in heat, we will get 1 which is violating Carnot's theorem that no process can have efficiency 1 - how can that be?

Comment: Oh!! i think i got an idea about entropy but what about other questions

Comment: 1. Those three questions are rather unrelated, please ask them seperately. 2. Please have a look at the edits I made to your post. Words at the beginning of sentences and names of persons are capitalized, punctuation symbols are *never* repeated directly after each other (in particular "......" does never appear), and you don't choose them at random - use a period (.) for sentences and a question mark (?) for questions and an exclamation mark (!) for exclamations. Exclamations rarely have a place in posts here - if unsure, use a period instead.

Comment: why the question is on hold

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your points 2 and 3:

- 2.) If you consider entropy as a chaos factor, then it is easier to grasp. The 2nd law of thermodynamics then says that entropy can only rise (or remain constant) for a process - this means that you can only get more chaos. Fx, if you mix ink into a pool, the water and ink will mix - it will not seperate. This process will always go towards the most chaotic and random state, which is the most mixed state. So actually, this law says something about direction of reactions and processes.

  In reality entropy is calculated from the number of possible *microstates*. These are namely the features that determine chaos. Many possible microstates means many possible outcomes - in other words, more randomness / less knowledge, because we know less about the system if the system can take many different micro-states / more chaos.

  A good example is when you flip coins. If you flip four coints, what is the most likely overall outcome? That will be 2 heads and 2 tails. Why? Because this outcome has the most possible "micro-states" (there are many ways to have 2 heads and 2 tails). Similarly, having 4 heads is much more unlikely, because only 1 micro-state gives this result (namely the micro-state where they are all heads). This "process" will always tend towards the state of most micro-states, simply because that is the most propable outcome. Other are possible but unlikely - scale this up to many, many, MANY atoms for example, and it becomes ridiculous unlikely that oxygen and hydrogen will *unmix* instead of mixing, or that water and ink will *unmix* instead of mixing or that a tempered room will suddenly become cold in one half and hot in the other half because the temperature "unmixed".
- 3.) You are right that for a cyclic process, $Q=W$. But remember here that $Q$ is *net* heat (and $W$ is net work). In a heat engine, you add heat $Q_H$ to get work $W$ and then cool it down to remove excess heat $Q_C$. See the picture below.

  There will always be heat loss as $Q_C$ - just like when water falls from a waterfall and hits a mill-wheel to turn it to do $work$; the water will be slowed down and will move slower below the mill-wheel but it will not stop. There will always be some (kinetic) energy in the water that won't be converted into work (rotation).

  So, in reality $Q=Q_H-Q_C$. When you find the efficiency, then always ask "*How much work did I get out of **the energy that I put in***". Efficiency is always usefull energy compared to energy input - wasted energy is skipped. The efficiency is therefore: $\eta = Q_H/W$ and not just $Q/W$.

[image]

Comment: that was cool!!!! but is there any way to calculate a useful energy only

Comment: @sharafzaman What do you mean by useful energy? The work $W$ *is* the useful energy (the energy that you get out of this process) which you could use in a generator or something else. In other cases useful energy is different - fx in a light bulb you would measure "efficiency" by how much energy you add compared to how much light energy you see or something like that. So it depends on the situation, but for heat engines, the described $\eta$ is the efficiency by convention

Comment: i mean how to calculate only the heat we supplied not which is given out to get efficiency

Comment: @sharafzaman That has to be given. You have to know that in another way. Usually you also do know the amount of inputted energy in a real life process like a powerplant, because you know exactly how much fuel you put in